# Negative signed value of a variable in C++

Tags: c++

I want to compare a variable with another variable in both of the positive and negative magnitudes.

```
unsigned a =20;
unsigned var = 400;
if( -var < a && a < var )
{
  //true if 20 is greater than (-400) and less than 400
}
```

Can I compare these two variables like this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And the question is... ??

Comment: When `var` is unsigned, what do you expect `-var` to be?

Comment: @stark I think it doesn't really matter, `-var = -1 * var` and the return value is treated as unsigned value, kinda like when you use `1.0 * var` and get back a double value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard,

> (*§ 5.3.1, Unary operators, 8*) The negative of an unsigned quantity is computed by subtracting its
>   value from 2^n , where n is the number of bits in the promoted
>   operand.

So, if you declare `var` as `unsigned var = 400;`, the value `-var` is actually **4294966896** (considering a 32bit representation) and the condition `-var < a` in your example become (4294966896 < 20).

If you are trying to check if an `int` variable (signed) `a` is in the range -400 < a < 400 you could do this:

```
int a = 20;
unsigned var = 400;
if( static_cast<unsigned>(std::abs(a)) < var )
{
  //true if 20 is greater than (-400) and less than 400
}
```

Comment: It's customary to mention the source when quoting something, even if it is The Standard.

Comment: @molbdnilo Edited, thanks. I referred to the working draft N4618, in case the wording (or position) is changed.

Comment: Yup, this is my favourite answer of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Awkwardly asked, but you're right to be careful as you're mixing in unsigned in there.

In your case, both a and var are unsigned, so your test should be simply be if a is less than var as you **know** that neither a not var can be less than zero.

In a more general case, use std::abs() to get the absolute value (ie the value with the sign always positive) and compare that.. so if a and var were signed..

```
if (std::abs(a) < std::abs(var))
```

In extreme case you may have to worry as the the largest negative number cannot be represented as a positive number but if you're anywhere near those sorts of limits you should cast to double (or long or long log etc) and then abs those value.

And generally steer clear of unsigned where you can (valid size_t etc uses notwithstanding)